# Маппинг многомерной структуры данных

Tags: java, nosql

У меня есть структура данных:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Hello",
"hotel": {
 "floors": 3,
  "phone": "333-22-44"
  "rooms": [
    {
     "beds": 3
      ...
    }....
   ]
   ...
   }
```

Какое лучшее решение для маппинга этой структуры на сущности и обратно в json файл?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я обычно использую [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Библиотека очень много всего разного умеет, самый простой юзкейс у нее это как раз Ваш вариант:

---

Для десериализации необходимо и достаточно завести в программе классы, описывающие структуру Вашего json, а затем вызвать

```
YourClass yourClassInstance = new ObjectMapper().readValue("{...}", YourClass.class);
```

---

для сериализации:

```
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(yourClassInstance);
```

---

```
public class jackson {

    static String JSON = "{" +
            "\"id\": 1," +
            "\"name\": \"Hello\"," +
            "\"hotel\": {" +
            "  \"floors\": 3," +
            "  \"phone\": \"333-22-44\"," +
            "  \"rooms\": [{" +
            "     \"beds\": 3" +
            "    }]" +
            "  }" +
            "}";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Trip trip = objectMapper.readValue(JSON, Trip.class);
        System.out.println("trip = " + trip);
        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(trip);
        System.out.println("json = " + json);
    }
}
```

---

**console:**

> ```
> trip = Trip{id=1, name='Hello', hotel=Hotel{floors=3, phone='333-22-44', rooms=[Room{beds=3}]}}
> json = {"id":1,"name":"Hello","hotel":{"floors":3,"phone":"333-22-44","rooms":[{"beds":3}]}}
> ```

---

```
public class Trip {

    public long id;
    public String name;
    public Hotel hotel;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Trip{id=" + id + ", name='" + name + "', hotel=" + hotel + '}';
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Hotel {
    public int floors;
    public String phone;
    public List<Room> rooms;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Hotel{floors=" + floors + ", phone='" + phone + "', rooms=" + rooms + '}';
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Room {
    public int beds;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Room{beds=" + beds + '}';
    }
}
```

---

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```